# How to edit claims in ID Token supplied with access token in django Oauth toolkit?

Tags: python, django, django-oauth-toolkit

When working with Django OAuth Toolkit, using OIDC if you supply `openid` as the `scope` in request you get a `id_token` with access token.
This ID Token can initially be used to identify the user you have got access token for and also create a session.

[image: This is what i am getting in JWT ID Token]

```
{
 "aud": "audience",
 "iat": 1681801110,
 "at_hash": "hash of included access token",
 "sub": "1",
 "given_name": "Dushyant",
 "preferred_username": "dsh",
 "iss": "authEndpointurl",
 "exp": 1681837110,
 "auth_time": 1681567804,
 "jti": "tokenid"
}
```

But I wish to modify the claims in this JWT ID Token, it reveals the primary key of the database of Authorization Server as the `unique id` of the user which i don't want in the claim called `sub`.
I want to use another unique key as the value of `sub` claim.
I tried overriding the response a Custom Backend:

```
class CustomOAuthBackend(OAuthLibCore):
def __init__(self, server):
    super().__init__(server)
    
def create_token_response(self, request):
    response_data = super().create_token_response(request)
    #Modify the response here
    return response_data
```

And added this as the Custom Backend in the settings.
`"OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS":"pathto.CustomOAuthBackend",`

I haven't written any modification code for the response here since the token here is already created When I am calling the original create_token_response.

**I want to override it in a way that I can modify the claims dict, I am not sure where it is getting created. We get the id_token all prepared. I want to override the process of creating id_token and change `sub` claim value.**

Let me know if any more information is required.

Update 1:
While looking for a possible solution, found oauth2_provider.oauth2_validators have methods `get_oidc_claims()` and `get_id_token_dictionary()` which looks like could lead to a possible solution. Figuring out how to use it.

There is a write up in the code

> This method is OPTIONAL and is NOT RECOMMENDED.
> `finalize_id_token` SHOULD be implemented instead. However, if you
> want a full control over the minting of the `id_token`, you
> MAY want to override `get_id_token` instead of using
> `finalize_id_token`.

This write up talks about `get_id_token()` method. Going through the code I see that `finalize_id_token()` is the method where JWT is created from claims.
This method calls `get_id_token_dictionary` then this internally calls `get_oidc_claims()` then this calls `get_claim_dict(request)`. get_claim_dict(request) only takes a request while others take token etc also. This method looks correct to override as this actually adds that `sub` claim to claims.

```
def get_claim_dict(self, request):
    if self._get_additional_claims_is_request_agnostic():
        claims = {"sub": lambda r: str(r.user.id)}
    else:
        claims = {"sub": str(request.user.id)}

    # https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims
    if self._get_additional_claims_is_request_agnostic():
        add = self.get_additional_claims()
    else:
        add = self.get_additional_claims(request)
    claims.update(add)

    return claims
```

I can get claims from this modify it and return the new updated claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by the same process I mentioned in the question.
At the end I override `get_claim_dict(self, request)` method.

```
class CustomOAuth2Validator(OAuth2Validator):

  def get_claim_dict(self, request):
       claims = super().get_claim_dict(request)
       claims["sub"] = lambda request: get_user_guid(request=request)
       return claims
```

I override the get_claim_dict in **OAuth2Validator**.
Add this validator as custom validator in django settings `"OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS": "pathTo.CustomOAuth2Validator",`

On decoding the JWT ID Token you will get the new value.

[image: Got New Sub Value]